# Добавление в ArrayList Color

Tags: java, android

Немного изменила....
У меня тут выводятся отрицательные числа хотелось бы сам цвет.
И еще...если у меня будет два адаптера как их обе вывести?А то у меня последний адаптер только выводится

```
ArrayAdapter adapter1;

 ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList();

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
colors.add(Color.RED);
colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
colors.add(Color.GREEN);
colors.add(Color.BLACK);
colors.add(Color.BLUE);
 }
Collections.shuffle(colors);
gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMain);
TextView tvvv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvv);
    adapter1=new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,R.id.tvv,colors);

gvMain.setAdapter(adapter1);
GridView();
}

private void GridView() {
gvMain.setNumColumns(5);
}
```

Comment: _У меня тут выводятся отрицательные числа_ - а должны выводиться...? В каком-то формате наверное? Или текст, или фон должен покраситься в этот цвет? Разъясните как можно подробнее свою проблему.

Comment: @woesss 
Как можно вывести 20 штук TextView чтоб цвет фона TextView выбирался случайным образом из массива color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте свой adapter, в котором вы принимаете массив цветов и с помощью метода

```
public static int getRandom(int[] array) {
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
    return array[rnd];
}
```

Возвращаете случайный цвет

Comment: Адаптер есть,правильно ли я его создала?И куда этот метод впихнуть и как ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    TextView colorText = findViewById(R.id.color_text);
    int [] colors = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW};//Массив с цветами
    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int number = 0 + rnd.nextInt((colors.length - 1) - 0 + 1);
    colorText.setBackgroundColor(colors[number]);//Получаем рандомный цвет
```

Comment: Не открывает приложение . Может в адаптере дело?                                                              
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tv);